# Some kind of projection in a non-orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Sorry if the title sounds convoluted,  I couldn't find any better.

> In $R^d$, let $(e_1,\ldots, e_d)$ be a basis. Show there exists $(a_1,\ldots, a_d)$ d vectors of $R^d$ such that $$\forall x \in R^d,  x=\sum_{i=1}^{d} \langle x, e_i \rangle a_i $$

I tried to mimic the proof of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization,  but failed. 
After that,  I introduced a linear mapping of which it suffices to prove the injectivity but it yields awful computations...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your basis have some property? (orthogonal, normal?)

Comment: @rlartiga no,  unfortunately...

Comment: I think I might see how a linear mapping from $\Bbb R^d$ to $\Bbb R^d$ might prove to be the right path. Maybe you can prove injectivity by writing down the inverse of the mapping?

Comment: @GregMartin Well since it's linear it might be more simple to prove that the Ker is $0$. This led to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720086/proving-that-exists-a-forall-x-xtga-0-rightarrow-a-0?lq=1 . Can you write the inverse mapping explicitly ?

Comment: Aren't we just looking for a *dual basis*, where $a_i\cdot e_i=1$, $a_i\cdot e_j=0$ for $i\ne j$?

Comment: @GarryMyerson Can you elaborate?

Comment: @GarryMyerson I see what you mean. But how do you prove that the linear forms we're dealing with are linearly independent?

Comment: @GarryMyerson I found it. I'll write it as an answer tomorrow

Comment: That's good, Gabriel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

Consider the $d$ following linear forms $\begin{array}{ccccc}
f_i & : & E & \to & \mathbb R \\
 & & x & \mapsto & \langle x|e_i\rangle \\
\end{array}$

We first prove that $(f_1,...,f_d)$ is a linearly independent family (hence a basis) of the dual space $E^*$: it suffices to prove that $\operatorname{rank}(f_1,...,f_d)=d $.

But $$\operatorname{rank}(f_1,...,f_d)=d-\dim(\cap_{i=1}^d \ker f_i)$$
$$\operatorname{rank}(f_1,...,f_d)=d-\dim(\cap_{i=1}^d \{e_i\}^\bot)$$

Since $(e_1,...,e_d)$ is a basis, 
$$\operatorname{rank}(f_1,...,f_d)=d-0=d$$

Therefore  $(f_1,...,f_d)$ is basis of $E^*$, which has a unique "prebasis" $(a_1,...,a_d)$ where $(a_1,...,a_d)$ is a basis of $E$ and $a_i^*=f_i$.

Now, $$\forall x \in E, x=\sum_{i=1}^{d} a_i^*(x) a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{d} f_i(x) a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{d} \langle x|e_i\rangle a_i$$

This achieves the proof.

**Solution 2**

Here : [Proving that $\exists A, \forall X, X^TGA=0 \Rightarrow A=0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720086/proving-that-exists-a-forall-x-xtga-0-rightarrow-a-0?lq=1)