# Proving that $\exists A, \forall X, X^TGA=0 \Rightarrow A=0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

After working on this [Some kind of projection in a non-orthogonal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719755/some-kind-of-projection-in-a-non-orthogonal-basis) , it turns out it suffices (ask why if you can't figure it) to solve the following problem:

> Suppose the existence of $a_1,...a_d$ be $d$ real numbers, and $\mathbf{e_1,\ldots,e_d}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^d$ such that $$\forall (x_1,...,x_d) \in \mathbb R^d, \sum_{i=1}^{d} \sum_{k=1}^{d} x_k \langle \mathbf{e_k,e_i} \rangle a_i=0 $$
> Prove that $a_1=\ldots=a_d=0$.

Equivalently, and more simply,

> Let $\mathbf{e_1,\ldots,e_d}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^d$ and $G$ the associated Gramian matrix.
>
> If there exists $A \in \mathcal{M}_{d,1}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall X \in \mathcal{M}_{d,1}(\mathbb R), X^TGA=0$, prove that $A=0$

How do I tackle this ? (I don't know much about Gramian matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ have the desired property.

[The Gram matrix $G$ is invertible if, and only if, $\{e_1,\ldots,e_d\}$ is a linearly indepedent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/gram-matrix-invertible-iff-set-of-vectors-linearly-independent).

One can prove that $\forall X \in \mathcal{M}_{d,1}(\mathbb R)\left(X^TGA=\mathbf 0\right)$ implies $GA=\mathbf 0$ and since $G$ is invertible, the desired result follows.

To prove that $\forall X \in \mathcal{M}_{d,1}(\mathbb R)\left(X^TGA=\mathbf 0\right)\implies GA=\mathbf 0$, note that  $\forall X \in \mathcal{M}_{d,1}(\mathbb R)\left(X^TGA=\mathbf 0\right)$ entails in particular $u_iGA=\mathbf 0$, for all $i\in \{1, \ldots ,d\}$, where each $u_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ vector of the standard basis.
This in turn implies that a certain $d\times d$ matrix $B$ has the property $BGA=\mathbf 0$. This $B$ is very special. Can you find it?

Comment: The identity of course! Your answer is very insightful,  thanks.

Comment: @GabrielR. You're welcome.